# Similar plugin to GuideGuide for illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, plugin

I really like the [GuideGuide](http://guideguide.me/) plugin for Photoshop that really quickly allows you to setup guides.

Is there something similar to this in illustrator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GuideGuide](https://guideguide.me/) is now available for Illustrator (CC+)

Answer (score 22):

You don't need GuideGuide. You can use the canned Illustrator features.

- Draw a rectangle to match your outer dimensions.
- Choose Object > Path > Split Into Grid.
- enter the rows and columns you want and any gutters between them and click OK.
  [image: split into grid]
- Choose View > Guides > Make Guides.

You can also tick the "Add Guides" option to automatically create guides which align to the rows and columns.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can pull a guide from a ruler, and select the guide and define x and y coordinate (for vertical guide x coordinate, and for horizontal y coordinate)

[image]

Comment: It's worth adding that you need to show rulers (`cmd-d`) first, and then to select the guides to set exact co-ordinates, you need to untick `View > Guides > Lock guides`