# How to quickly and easily create a grid with Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, workflow, grids, measurement

Suppose I need to draw a grid in Photoshop, each square being the same size, and a certain amount of pixels tall and wide, and the grid lines having a certain pixel width. Like this:

[image: 10 by 10 grid of white squares on a black background. Black borders all around the square as well]

Currently I do this by drawing one square, copy+pasting+moving+merging it a few times to create one row, copy/pasting that a few times to create more rows above each other.

It works, but feels very clumsy, I'm sure there ought to be a more efficient way to do this?

**What are some efficient methods for creating a grid of equally sized squares?**

Comment: If you have Illustrator, I'd do it there. See This: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/similar-plugin-to-guideguide-for-illustrator/16870#16870 -- then simply copy/paste to Photoshop.

Answer (score 70):

Try using patterns.  For your example of a square:

Draw your initial square and marquee-select a smaller square that includes the top and left sides only. Then select `Edit > Define Pattern...` and save your pattern with a name.

Next, marquee-select the area that you wish to fill. Then select `Edit > Fill...` , choose `Use: Pattern` and select your square pattern.

[image]

Comment: how can you make it so there are no half cells, in that it fits perfectly?

Comment: In the example above, I used the info palette to measure the grid-size. In this case, it was 86px.

If you want to tile a canvas without 'half-cells', use a value that multiplies evenly into your canvas dimensions.

Comment: Well, I have the layer in which I drew the square selected and the marquee all set up, yet Edit > Define Pattern is a disabled menu choice for me. Baffling.

Answer (score 7):

If you are attempting to create a grid just for your benefit while designing, there's an extension named [GuideGuide](http://guideguide.me/) that will do this efficiently.

If you need the grid to be part of the design, I'd recommend creating a line using the marquee tool and then duplicating it as many times as you need, then using the `Layer >> Distribute` options to get them perfectly even.

Comment: it isn't necessary to pay extra for this stuff... New Guide Layout does it in Photoshop 2020 https://gyazo.com/aef7c388f068cfbd0a29af750df3c7a1

Answer (score 6):

Under the "view" tab
New Guide layout

this will open a new window
Preset - you can save, load & create a guide layout to use over and over again
check or uncheck columns or rows depending on your needs
I suggest having "preview" checked
Number = The number of guides you desire
Width = The distance between the generated guides
Gutter = the space between guides
Margin = sets your designs desired margins, you can type in a value for top, left, bottom and right

center columns and clear existing guides can be selected as well

This is for Photoshop CC 2015.5

Answer (score 3):

1. Select *photoshop → preferences → guides, grids & slices.*
2. Define grid as desired
3. Select *view → show → grid;* then check *extras.*
4. Check *view → snap to grid;* then check *snap.*
5. Turn on the *Paths* window if it isn’t already visible. Create a new path called *Horizontal.*
6. Use the *pen* tool (<kbd>P</kbd>). Define a horizontal line segment at the top of the grid. Single click first on left side, then the right.
7. Use the *path selecetion* tool (<kbd>A</kbd>, black arrow). Click on the path, hold down *option* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>) to make copies of the object.
8. Create another new path called *vertical.*
9. Use the *pen* tool (<kbd>P</kbd>). Define a vertical line segment of the grid on the left side. Single click first on the top, then the bottom.
10. Use the *path selection* tool (<kbd>A</kbd>, black arrow). Click on the path, hold down *option* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>) to make copies of the object.
11. Create a new layer for the grid (optional). Otherwise, the grid will be drawn on whichever layer is active.
12. *Palette* window  → Select *horizontal* path, then choose *stroke path* (using foreground color) from the options submenu (click the little triangle with three lines on the upper right corner of the palette window), choose brush or pencil.
13. Repeat previous step to stroke the *vertical* path.

Comment: That is a tremendous amount of work to do it like this.

Comment: Actually, that was quite quick for me. Is there any better way to create a grid of paths (rather than pixels)? Very neat having it snap to the grid. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found a quick way to solve my problem (I have PS CS4): I used "Show Grid", adjusted the size etc in Preferences, got it exactly how I wanted it, and then took a screenshot of the image, Pasted it into my file as a new layer, and trimmed it to size & scale.  This will not be hi-res enough for some users, but it was super-quick and worked for my needs.