# How to align all selected points to a grid?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids

I'm working with Illustrator to make some icons. I use grid with step = 1px and after I scale/rotate shape elements I want them to automatically align to the grid. I know CS4+ has such an option in transform settings, but I have only CS2 at hand and I was hoping that there's some other way of aligning selected points to the grid (hidden option, script?).

At the moment I'm selecting each point and manually move it up-left them down-right so that it snaps to a grid, but that is VERY slow and prone to mistakes.

Is there a way in Adobe Illustrator CS2 to align all selected points to a grid?

**UPDATE:** Changed the question details: it should read **grid** instead of *pixel grid* (otherwise it was misleading).

Comment: It would be nice if downvoter could explain his motivation, maybe question can be improved? )

Comment: It would be nice if **now 2** downvoters could explain their positions.

Comment: No idea what the downvotes were for - this is a really clear question. On some StackExchange sites there's a really ugly undignified trend where some people downvote questions when they don't know the answer... (i.e. any interesting, challenging questions...) I *really* hope that's not what happened here because I thought we were better than that.

Comment: 2 downvotes = -4, here's an upvote = +10. You're now at +6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

---

### Scripting

The [John Wundes script Pixel Align](http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/) should be a good starting point. I don't have CS2 to test with, but I think it should work with CS2 (the notes seem to say that it's tested and works in CS1, so CS2 should be fine).

The approach the script uses is really simple: it loops through all objects and uses `math.round()` to round their `top`, `left` and where appropriate (i.e. lines), their `height` and `width` to the nearest whole number.

You'd need to adapt it so that, for paths, it loops through each point instead of each object. Any script that applies to all points could be a starting point (OP suggested [Organify](http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/) from the same source).

---

### Save as SVG feature

This lets you choose how many **decimal places** the exported SVG uses to describe things like anchor positions (so people can reduce file size if they don't need super accuracy).

**Set it to 0 decimal places**, and it'll round anchor points to nearest whole number - i.e. nearest pixel.

So, save as SVG with 0 decimal places, reload, and you should see your image effectively snapped to a pixel grid. Then save as whatever format you need.

Be aware that things like curve angles will also be rounded so check it hasn't mucked up any important details.

Also be aware that snapping to a 1px grid might not give the results you intend when using strokes. For example, a line with a 1px stroke snapped to a 1px grid may give you 0.5px above the line and 0.5px below - you might need to set strokes to inside or outside, or move 1px stroked objects up/down/left/right by 0.5px after they are "snapped" to the grid.

**Edit**: the asker reports that for them, this almost works, but there are very small differences to the exact positions (presumably due Illustrator having somewhat ropey SVG support).

Comment: SVG idea sounds nice (CS2 allows decimals from 1 to 7) and after the trick the points are indeed seem to be rounded to the grid, but the alignment is still off by some minor value. Simple check - I select 1 point, press *right* it jumps 1 cell right, but if I press *left* instead it jumps 2 cells left. That is the same behavior unaligned points show. So probably what happens is that precision gets lost and points get aligned to something alike 14.9998 or 15.0001 instead of 15.0.

Comment: If it's a minor value it's likely to be consistent (or, very very similar) for every point - so can't you then move all points at once to get them exactly on the grid?

Comment: There's another question there, how to see fractional part of points position? When I select any point it's position is shown rounded to closest integer.

Comment: On a sidenote, it looks like if I'll combine *Organify* and *PixelAlign* from the link you have posted, it will provide the exact result I need. Will test that in few hours.

Comment: It worked almost perfectly! If I may, I want you to focus your answer on scripting and if you can, mention that taking Organify script by John and using `Math.round` in it produces the desired result! You get my best regards user568458 :)

Comment: It would be more flexible if you were to round to a variable grid, and not just use Math.round():
`var gridVal = 1; function roundPoint (p) { var j = p % gridVal; p = (j > gridVal / 2) ? Math.floor(p + gridVal - j) : Math.floor(p - j); }`

Comment: Great idea Alex, luckily I use 1px grid, so rounding to 1 is fine with me, but for others that might be useful. Can you elaborate, how to access/see current grid step?

Comment: In this case, the grid-quantization would be held as a value in the code. But if you were to use an interface, you could easily change it on the fly. Or perhaps have it encoded in the name of the artboard, layer, file info, etc.

Comment: It would be best to be able to grab the value from Illustrator settings and I'm sure there's a way scripts can access that, but as I said - I have already got what I wanted and other with similar problems have a pretty good direction where to look for - Illustrator scripting forum.

Comment: @KromStern if those links helped you make a script that works and if you don't mind sharing it for other people facing the same problem, you could edit the working script into the end of the answer. People could then also edit in new features or improvements if they wanted.

Comment: I'm afraid if I so largely edit your answer (remove SVG parts and expand scripts part) it won't pass through peer-review, but I still want you to get the bounty. My suggestion: You edit your answer the way I described and then I add script part to it and award you deserved bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

How about [this script](http://labs.ideo.com/2011/04/21/pixel-perfect-illustrator-tips/). It claims to snap all illustrator objects to the nearest pixel. Not sure if it works on points as well as objects...

---

Not ideal, but you could save some time by manually type the X or Y position at the top.

If you have a lot of objects sort-of aligned, you could grab them all at once and type in a rounded number into your X or Y field to snap them into position on that axis.

Comment: I tried and manually selecting each point and moving it up-left then down-right is quite faster, but still a total disaster even for 100 points. Still thanks for reply )

Comment: The `Window > Align` panel might help also (assuming it exists in CS2)

Comment: You should check out [this thread](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/similar-plugin-to-guideguide-for-illustrator). It claims to be the Illustrator equiv. of GuideGuide which is a tool in Photoshop to create a grid of guides. Guides have snapping, which might help more than the standard grid.

Comment: I believe you got my question a bit wrong. I was looking into points alignment to a grid, not objects. I have existing free-form objects (which form up an icon) that I need to scale and rotate sometimes and after I do that I need to keep the nice alignment to a grid (which has a step = 1px) so that upon export I have nice pixel-perfect icons.

Comment: @KromStern updated answer

Comment: That script is basically the same as the pixelalign script I linked to - it only aligns objects, not points within objects

Comment: Thanks again John, but the question is specifically about aligning all selected **points** to the grid, not the objects, for the reasons explained above