# Illustrator CC : Distributing Objects (spacing)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, alignment, cc-2015

I'm having an issue re-spacing the dots on the map below evenly. I created the whole thing in Illustrator and somehow missed that spacing issue in the early stages. Needless to say the issue repeats throughout my final product. I was hoping to fix for equal space between all of the dots without having to start from scratch with the blend tool.

[image]

The shapes are irregular and I need the dots to all be complete on the map (no half dots on the edges).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Here's the actual AI file if anyone wants to give her a looksie:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztfd4p2t2ms7h5p/Vector%20Smart%20Object.ai?dl=0

Thank ya!

Comment: Hi @Belinda Wellcome to GDSE Can you show what you have tried so far when trying to reach that effect and explain the steps you used. the file you post it don not explain how did you get that effect? it is not possible to draw a circle filling the map one by one.

Comment: Are you sure its not just a moire effect of your chosen spacing and screen

Comment: Couldn't you just use a pattern fill? If half circles at the boundaries are a problem either adjust the path or expand and delete any circles that aren't completely within the boundary

Comment: This question may help: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25365/how-to-align-all-selected-points-to-a-grid

Comment: @Belinda Vega   I know exactly what you are trying to achieve but unfortunately I have no clue as to how this can be accomplished. In fact, it seems like function that should have been available. In fact, what would be nice is the ability to rescale the image where the spacing between increases relative to the overall shape. Would love to know of there is indeed a solution.

Comment: What I did initially was create a small portion of the squares and aligned vertically and horizontally. Then I copy + pasted along the artboard and aligned each grouped section vertically and horizontally. This alone is a menu for trouble, apparently. According to "the law of Illustrator land" the alignment tools are finicky.

Comment: My husband came to the rescue before I could trash the whole thing and start over. The answer to it was a script he wrote to align everything perfectly apart from each other without compromising the grid I had going for it.

Comment: While he was working on the script, I threw down some ideas. Basically, my error was in the very first step. 

The best way to have achieved an evenly spaced dotted background would've been to create a line of dots to the left or top of the page, aligned proportionally to each other via the Blend Tool. Copy + paste that line of dots once across the page, Expand both lines of dots, then use the Blend Tool to create the rest of the page with the 'specified distance' option by selecting the starting point and the ending point.

Comment: I've learned my lesson with the alignment tool and multiple objects. I'll call this lesson "Illustrator, you cray"

Comment: Thank you all for the discussion. Indeed the final answer was the script and the SVG save at 3 decimal spaces as addressed in Cal Morris' reply. This enabled me to not have to scrap it all and start from beginning. Because of this fix, we were able to trudge on with this already set piece and reset the full alignment to perfection.

Answer (score 1):

Actually recreating this effect is fairly easy, all you need to do is:
1- import your map (as image)
2- go to Object>create object mosaic (set your desired sizes and spacing).

The result will be a pattern of squares. If you want circles pattern, simply select all squares and increase the corner radius.

Voila! you have your map created from small circles and with the right spacing.

[image]